# Better way to use same ember validation rules between Add and Edit controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-validations

I'm using ember-validations and what is in Ember the right way to use the same validation rules between Add and Edit controller?

Doing this it is not the DRY way

```
App.UsersAddUserController.reopen(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
    validations: {
        name: {
            presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 3 }
        },
        surname: {
            presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 3 }
        }
    },
});

App.UsersEditUserController.reopen(Ember.Validations.Mixin, {
    validations: {
        name: {
            presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 3 }
        },
        surname: {
            presence: true,
            length: { minimum: 3 }
        }
    },
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Either

```
App.UsersEditUserController = App.UsersAddUserController.extend({})
```

Or Tell route which controller to use

```
App.UsersEditUserRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  controllerName: 'usersAddUser'
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way:

```
App.UserValidations = {
  validations: {
    name: {
      presence: true,
      length: { minimum: 3 }
    },
    surname: {
      presence: true,
      length: { minimum: 3 }
    }
  }
}

App.UsersAddUserController.reopen(Ember.Validations.Mixin, App.UserValidations);
App.UsersEditUserController.reopen(Ember.Validations.Mixin, App.UserValidations);
```